# Calculating accept rate

Tags: support, accepted-answer

Do open questions with no answers affect my accept rate? I can't calculate it on my own because my rate isn't displayed anywhere I can see, but that's probably another question.

Comment: See [this question on Meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work)

Comment: IOW, no. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taken from the [Meta.SO Post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16721/how-does-accept-rate-work/16729#16729) on accept rates:

> **Which questions do not affect the accept rate?**
>
> The following questions are not included in the accept rate
>   calculation:
>
> ```
> Community Wiki Questions
> Closed Questions
> Questions with no answers
> ```

Thanks to [@bckbck](https://meta.superuser.com/users/78429/bckbck) for answering it in the comments originally.

Comment: Already answered in the @bckbck's comment.

Comment: Which is why I put it as an answer so the question could be finished.